# how to write jest snapshot of conditional rendering in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot

How to handle a snapshot of the below code. I want to create 3 snapshot test

```
const Home = () => {
  const apiStausCode = 200
  const apiError = "error" 
  if(apiStausCode === 200) {
    return (
      <h1>title</h1>
    )
  } else if (apiError) {
    return <LoadingError />
  } else {
    return <Spinner />
  }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Hi. Why do you feel you need a snapshot? `> I want to create 3 snapshot test` What 3 things do you need to test?

Comment: I mean one file includes 3 snapshots. like one snapshot for LoadingError, Spinner, h1 tag section.

Comment: Yep. Why snapshots though? Have you tried testing the content instead? [Example](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/example-intro)

Comment: i want to cover all code .  now 'return (' display 'statement not covered ' text & if else section display 'if path not taken'.

Comment: You will need to control the `statusCode` and `error` via props. That way, you can create 3 tests and pass them with different props and observe the behaviour. You wouldn't need snapshot tests for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 things

- Write separate test cases for each condition.
- use `beforeEach(jest.resetAllMocks)` before starting `describe` block